# How to do javascript scripting in BIRT report?

Tags: javascript, birt, actuate

Can someone give me references where I can learn about javascript scripting in BIRT reports?

Scenario is, I have a drop down where which contains name of all car companies... Along with it, it has **ALL** option.
When "**ALL**" option is selected it should display all the records of all car brands.

Currently when I select individual car names, it works fine.
ALL option is not working.

Here is a code snippet.

```
if (params["RP_CarCompany_Name"].value == 'ALL') {
    this.queryText = this.queryText.replace('DYNAMIC_CARCOMPANY', "'" + 'BMW' + "'," + "'" + 'AUDI' + "'," + "'" + 'JEEP' + "'," + "'" + 'DATSUN' + "'");
} else {
    this.queryText = this.queryText.replace('DYNAMIC_CARCOMPANY', "'" + params["RP_CarCompany_Name"].value.join("','") + "'");
}
```

P.S.: DYNAMIC_CARCOMPANY is a placeholder in SQL query which is something like this

```
SELECT * FROM CAR_DB WHERE carcompany IN(DYNAMIC_CARCOMPANY);
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Try : `this.queryText = this.queryText.replace('DYNAMIC_CARCOMPANY', "'BMW', 'AUDI', 'JEEP', 'DATSUN'");`

Comment: Please, could you log your query result (credit to Jason : https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/216762/): 

`importPackage( Packages.java.io );
 out = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( "c:/myquery.txt", true ) );
 out.println( "My Query: " + this.queryText);
 out.close();`

After your code. Edit your question with the result.

Comment: `this.queryText = this.queryText.replace('DYNAMIC_CARCOMPANY', "'" + ["BMW","AUDI","JEEP","DATSUN"].join("','")  + "'");`
This worked.